# how to reference the group name in {{for}} section in jsRender?

Tags: jsrender

```
{{for Person}}
<input type="text" value="{{>Name}}" name="{{>#data}}.Name" id="{{:#data}}.Name" />
{{/for}}
```

How can I output an input with name and id as `Person.Name`?

I tried a few ways but to no success so far. How should I obtain the name of the for variable?

Thanks.

----------------Update------------------

The example code above may be too concise. The one I am working on is an entity called `InjuryZone`, and there are nearly a hundred checkboxes for each zone:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="true" name="InjuryZones.UpperLeg" id="InjuryZones_UpperLeg" />
<input type="checkbox" value="true" name="InjuryZones.Knee" id="InjuryZones_Knee" />
...
```

I am thinking that I should be able to use some expression like `#data` or something to avoid duplicate `InjuryZones` everywhere in `name` and `id`.

But my understanding is `#data` shows the actual value instead of the name of the property. How can we repeat the string that comes after `{{for`? Is it possible?

Comment: are you wanting the name and id to be the actual string "Person.Name" or the value stored in the `Person` object with the key `Name`? Be careful that you don't end up creating multiple elements with the same id.

Comment: Sounds like all you want is `id="Person.{{>Name}}"`.
You already hard-coded 'Person' into the template, by writing `{{for Person}}`

Comment: Wow! So thrilled to see a comment from BorisMoore himself!!! Thank you for jsRender.